# Stop keyboard keys from affecting jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, accordion

i had a little peak around Stackoverflow and couldn't find the answer to this question.

On my website I have 2 Jquery elements.. Tabs and accordion. They look great but i'm having issues with the keyboard.

Because i use a netbook, i sometimes find it easier to surf pages just by pressing up or down on the keyboard.. However if a Jquery element is selected, i find myself cycling through seperate sections.

It seams Jquery has built-in key commands which i do not want. How can i remove all key commands?

It should only be possible to affect the elements with the mouse!

Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: What plugins are you using? Might be just a setting / option to disable keyboard events.

Comment: @putvande Sounds like he's using the jQuery UI Tabs and Accordion plugins.

Comment: Hey. Barmar is right. I'm using the Jquery UI Tabs and Accordion plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    $("#tabs li[role=tab]").unbind('keydown');
});
```

[fiddle (the basic template taken from jquery documentation)](http://jsfiddle.net/h2bRL/1/)

You can see that on the third tab where a scroll appears, it scrolls through the page when you press down and doesn't jump between tabs.

Comment: Improved first example